# Border Corners: Triangle

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get rid of the "triangle" shape in the border corners? (when using different color borders)

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GLsqV/

Any workaround? Basically I just want the top and bottom border to continue, and not have a mix of all of them.

```
 .borders {  
   width:500px;
   height:500px;
   background:#efefef;
   border:10px solid black;
   border-top:10px solid red;
   border-bottom:10px solid green;
 }​
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option using generated content:

```
.borders {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position: relative;
    background:#efefef;
    border-top:10px solid red;
    border-bottom:10px solid green;
}

.borders::before,
.borders::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

.borders::before {
    left: 0;
}

.borders::after {
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GLsqV/1/).

Or with nested HTML (if you really must):

```
<div class="borders">
    <div class="innerBorder left"></div>
    <div class="innerBorder right"></div>
</div>​

.borders {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    position: relative;
    background:#efefef;
    border-top:10px solid red;
    border-bottom:10px solid green;
}

.borders .innerBorder{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

.borders .left {
    left: 0;
}

.borders .right {
    right: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GLsqV/2/).

And a single-nested-element solution in which the left, and right, `border-color` is the `background-color` of the wrapping element, and the width controlled by the `margin` of the descendant:

```
<div class="borders">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.borders {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-color: #000;
    border-top:10px solid red;
    border-bottom:10px solid green;
}

.borders .inner {
    background-color: #efefef;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GLsqV/3/).​

Comment: One child element appears to be enough here. See my answer.

Comment: You're absolutely right! And...I've added one in (though, of course, it's a *different* single-descendant solution to your own) =)

Answer (score 2):

Not everywhere with a single element. (Actually, the default triangular shape of borders is what makes great things possible: [The Shapes of CSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/))

However, what you are asking for is easily possible everywhere with another child element.

CSS:

```
.borders {
  width: 520px;
  height: 500px;
  border-top: 10px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid green;
}

.borders2 {
  background: #efefef;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;    
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
}
```

​
HTML:

```
<div class="borders">
  <div class="borders2">
  </div>
</div>​
```

With these values, the outer `DIV`'s border-box will still have a size of 520×520 pixels.

See also [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KY6vP/1/).

Comment: @DavidThomas Dito. I have been using the `:before/:after { position: absolute; }` trick extensively for the logos in my [Seri-o-meter](http://PointedEars.de/media/video/series).

Answer (score 1):

That's how borders work. How would the browser decide which ones overlap the corners otherwise?

You can achieve this effect using a nested DIV, or using a trick with :before and :after with some absolute positioning.