# CSS Full Border top?

Tags: css, border

my `div` has different `border-top` color than its `left` and `right` border.

Example:

```
div{
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
    border-top: blue 20px solid;
    border-left: red 20px solid;
    border-right: red 20px solid;
}
```

But the corner of the border become tringle-shaped as shown in left-image below:

[image: CSS Border Problem]

I want the `border-top` to span full width like the right-image above.

Any trick to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459985/border-corners-triangle

Comment: possible duplicate of [set css border to end in a 90 instead of a 45 degree angle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261703/set-css-border-to-end-in-a-90-instead-of-a-45-degree-angle)

Comment: Thanks, I like the one that uses `::after` and `::before`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would gove you the desired result:

HTML

```
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
```

CSS

```
div#a {
    border-top: blue 20px solid;
    width: 140px;
}
div#b {
    height: 100px;
    border-left: red 20px solid;
    border-right: red 20px solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But I prefer [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13460111/1318622).