# My css ul li table roster is missing a pixel when hover changes the color

Tags: css, sass

[image: CSS missing parameter]

I have a hover that changes the color of the border-left, but it is missing a pixel. How can I fix this?

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#">First element</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Second element</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Third element</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {

   list-style-type:none;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;

   li {

       border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
       border-left: 3px solid #e5e5e5;

       &:hover {
           border-left-color: #be0928;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Borders have mitered corners:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/rhbuv0ou.  You're looking at the intended behavior due to your 1px solid top border.

Comment: Yup. You're actually not missing a pixel. You might find [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459985/border-corners-triangle) helps with creating the effect you want, but I don't think it can be done simply with a standard single border. Might be worth checking out CSS3's [border-image](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/); I don't know whether it'll help...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `box-shadow` property to mimic a border. As others mentioned in the comments, the `border` property is acting as intended.

Here's the CSS for the `box-shadow` trick:

```
li {
    padding: 3px 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    box-shadow: -3px 0 #e5e5e5;
    width:150px;
    float:left;

    &:hover {
        box-shadow: -3px 0 0 0 #be0928;
    }
}
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qWngJ/)